# How to initialize a class property List by adding Elements to it

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq

I did my research and as far as I know in C# is not possible to initialize a property say this one:

`public List<Activity> ActivityList { get; set; }`

With a `.Add()` method in one line of code like this:

```cs
ActivityList = new List<Activity>().Add(new Activity(){Code = smth.code});
```

That is because c# `.Add()` method returns void which is not of type `Generic.List<Activity>`

---

But in my case:

- I do not know how many elements the list will have so setting the elements statically won't work for me.
- Since populating the property list is done during a `.Select()` is not possible for me to declare a variable 'outside' and then use the `.Add()` method later. It has to be done in one line of code.

What can I try next?

### Update

```cs
var grps = from d in result1
group d by d.CommissionId
into grp
select new RegistrationStatisticViewModel() {
  CommissionId = grp.Key,
    ActivityList = grp.AsEnumerable().
  CommissionCode = grp.First().CommissionCode,
    CommissionDescription = grp.First().CommissionDescription,
    MinuteWorked = grp.First().MinuteWorked,
    ActivityId = grp.First().ActivityId,
    UserId = grp.First().UserId
};
return grps;
```

Where grp here has this each time:
**GRP**
[image: GRP]

i want that [0], [1], [2] elements to be put in the property list.

Comment: `List<T>` has a constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` of items to add, so you could use that.

Comment: `ActivityList = new List<Activity>(){ new Activity() { Code = smth.code } };`

Comment: @VDWWD "_I do not know how many elements the list will have so setting the elements statically won't work for me_".

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, you are right. I should have read better

Comment: If it is from a Select, maybe you are looking for this? `MyList.Select(x => new Activity() { code = x.code }).ToList();`

Comment: @VDWWD it's complicated and last time i shared the whole code on another answer everyone got scared and didn't reply to me anymore. If you want i can share my linq `.Select()` but without context is difficult to fully understand ahah